# Number of k-ary monotone maps from 1..n+1 to 1..n+1

Tags: co.combinatorics

[Remark: Last week I asked the same question at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601094/number-of-k-ary-monotone-maps-from-1-n1-to-1-n1) but I have not gotten any answer, so I have thought that there are more chances to get an answer (perhaphs partial) here]

Given natural numbers $k$ and $n$, I am interested in **what it is known about how many k-ary monotone maps there are from $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ to $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$**. At some point I though that the answer should be known (and perhaps there are even explicit recurrences to compute the number), but I have not succeeded to find any information (one of the problems is how to search for this).

Let me now clarify some details in the question. Such k-ary functions are the ones from $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}^k$ to $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ which are monotonic. The monotonicity is based in using the following partial orders:

- $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ with the natural (i.e., standard) one,
- $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}^k$ with the direct product of the natural one.

In particular, when $k \geq 2$ this last partial order is not linear.

At this moment the only information I have been able to find about these numbers is that:

- the sequence corresponding to the particular case that k=1 (and moving n) is https://oeis.org/A001700 (1, 3, 10, 35, 126, 462, 1716, 6435, 24310, 92378, 352716, etc.)
- the sequence corresponding to the particular case that n=1 (and moving k) is https://oeis.org/A000372 (which corresponds to what is known as Dedekind numbers, and it starts 2, 3, 6, 20, 168, 7581, 7828354, etc.)

So let me rephrase the above question as saying that I am interested in any (partial) answer to the following questions:

- how many binary monotone maps there are from $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ to $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$?
- how many 3-ary monotone maps there are from $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$ to $\{1,2,...,n,n+1\}$?
- etc.

Comment: Did you try searching for smth like Enumeration of nested Young diagrams?

Comment: @Ilya: Not at all. Do you see (or expect) some connection between "nested Young diagrams" and the monotonic functions of my question?